# Whole data is not retrieved from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am having a table in MySQL dB which is linked to my codeigniter project. I have kept the Data Type of varchar[1000] for the field 'aboutus_detail', in which I have stored a long passage. While I try to retrieve the data from the table, I did not get the whole data stored in the field 'aboutus_detail'.

[image: The Length of the 'aboutus_detail' is varchar[1000]]

[image: The data stored for the 'aboutus_detail']

I have used print_r(). I get the following output only

```
Array (
 [0] => Array (
      [aboutus_id] => 1 
      [aboutus_title] => India Nirman Sangh 
      [aboutus_detail] => Since 2005, we have been working in the hills around Kodaikanal and Palaniin Tamilnadu, India.Through these twelve years, we have workedtowards women’s development in the towns on the hills,and in Kodaikanal and Palani towns. Winning th 
      [aboutus_image] => files/slide1.jpg 
              )
      )
```

I have tried with Data Type as 'text'. Suggest a way so that I could retrieve the whole passage.

My Controller:

```
class Welcome extends My_Controller {

    public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('aboutus_model');
    $data['list'] = $this->aboutus_model->about_us_page();
    $this->load->view('about_us/about',$data);
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
class Aboutus_model extends CI_Model 
{
    public function about_us_page()
    {
        $data = $this->db->query('select * from ins_aboutus')->result_array();
        return $data;
    }

}
```

My view:

```
<?php print_r($list); exit; ?>
```

Comment: all get saved ??

Comment: try to use data type 'LONGTEXT' which is store up to 4 Gib

Comment: add code as well

Comment: @AbdullaNilam, All are getting saved

Comment: add code then...

Comment: `print_r($data); die;` in model and see

Comment: how many records in your table?

Answer (score 0):

try with this code in model.......

```
 class Aboutus_model extends CI_Model 
    {
        public function about_us_page()
        { 

     $data = $this->db->query('select * from ins_aboutus');
        return $data->result();

    }

}
```